# If I link Google analytics and adwords, will Google adwords be able to see my conversion rates and ROIs and change my ad cost?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

This may seem like a silly question, but I've not been able to find an answer anywhere in either StackOverflow or Google.

The question is, if I link my Google Analytics and Adwords accounts, in theory wouldn't Google be able to see my ROI? And if they see my ROI as incredibly high, couldn't they increase the PPC ad cost behind the scenes to make Google more money? I suppose, I could just trust Google to "do the right thing" to let the market-based algorithms dictate pricing. But let's say I'm paying $2.00 per click and making average $100 in revenue per click -- an outrageous ROI -- what's to stop Google from seeing this data and increasing the PPC cost to $5 or even $10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they don't do that. Anyone can set an arbitrary number as their conversion value and see an inflated ROI in their reports. There are more genuine use cases to do this than you imagine.

Second, your idea of how the market works is flawed. Google cannot arbitrarily increase costs (well, they can indirectly through quality score). The cost is determined by the bids of your competitors. If you and all your competitors got together and collided to decrease your bids, Google could do nothing and everyone would benefit (except Google). The fact that competition is geographically dispersed and online means this situation is unlikely so competitors bid based on the ROAS.

Besides, if Google were found to be doing this, nobody would use them anymore.